# Newsletter in Rails based on Timezone of User

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to update a users table with columns id, name , balance and timezone every day . were the balance get doubled. the function is very simple but the update has to happen every day for the user at 00:00 of his timezone.

my initial idea was to check users between timezone 1 and timezone 2 and update.

Im using Heroku Scheduler.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know what is the timezone of the user?

Comment: I want to know the approach of coding this situation. I have the users timezone, I have the current time zone of the server. but i Cant have the heroku scheduler to work based on each users time zone , i need to find an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Can you store the timezone of the user on creation, with a `before_save`, and schedule the job evry hour. You will find the user with something like this :

```
users = User.find_by_timezone('1234')
```

Comment: can you share the documentation of find_by_timezone method ?

Comment: this is not a specific method. It you have a field called timezone in your data base, rails "generate" the find_by_timezone method for your model.

Comment: The user model has a field called timezone but in the db column its a string, and find_by_timezone isn't working "undefined method find_by_timezone"

Comment: you can also use User.where('timezone = ?', 'the_timezone')

Answer (score 0):

## Break on Time of the user is not between 00:00 and 01:00

```
Time.zone = user.tz || 'UTC'

break if Time.zone.now.hour != 0
```